# How to overlap R histograms

Tags: r, histogram, survey

Reproduced from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64474714/run-svymean-on-all-variables) code:

```
library(haven)
library(survey)
library(dplyr)

nhanesDemo <- read_xpt(url("https://wwwn.cdc.gov/Nchs/Nhanes/2015-2016/DEMO_I.XPT"))

# Rename variables into something more readable
nhanesDemo$fpl <- nhanesDemo$INDFMPIR
nhanesDemo$age <- nhanesDemo$RIDAGEYR
nhanesDemo$gender <- nhanesDemo$RIAGENDR
nhanesDemo$persWeight <- nhanesDemo$WTINT2YR
nhanesDemo$psu <- nhanesDemo$SDMVPSU
nhanesDemo$strata <- nhanesDemo$SDMVSTRA

nhanesAnalysis <- nhanesDemo %>%
  mutate(LowIncome = case_when(
    INDFMIN2 < 40 ~ T,
    T ~ F
  )) %>%
  # Select the necessary columns
  select(INDFMIN2, LowIncome, persWeight, psu, strata)

# Set up the design
nhanesDesign <- svydesign(id      = ~psu,
                          strata  = ~strata,
                          weights = ~persWeight,
                          nest    = TRUE,
                          data    = nhanesAnalysis)

svyhist(~log10(INDFMIN2), design=nhanesDesign, main = '')
```

[image]

How do I color the histogram by independent variable, say, LowIncome? I want to have two separate histograms, one for each value of LowIncome. Unfortunately I picked a bad example, but I want them to be see-through in case their values overlap.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to plot a histogram from your model, you can get its data from `model.frame` (this is what `svyhist` does under the hood). To get the histogram filled by group, you could use this data frame inside `ggplot`:

```r
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(model.frame(nhanesDesign), aes(log10(INDFMIN2), fill = LowIncome)) +
  geom_histogram(alpha = 0.5, color = "gray60", breaks = 0:20 / 10) +
  theme_classic()
```

[image]

---

**Edit**

As Thomas Lumley points out, this does not incorporate sampling weights, so if you wanted this you could do:

```r
ggplot(model.frame(nhanesDesign), aes(log10(INDFMIN2), fill = LowIncome)) +
  geom_histogram(aes(weight = persWeight), alpha = 0.5, 
                 color = "gray60", breaks = 0:20 / 10) +
  theme_classic()
```

[image]

To demonstrate this approach works, we can replicate Thomas's approach in ggplot using the data example from `svyhist`. To get the uneven bin sizes (if this is desired), we need two histogram layers, though I'm guessing this would not be required for most use-cases.

```r
ggplot(model.frame(dstrat), aes(enroll)) +
  geom_histogram(aes(fill = "E", weight = pw, y = after_stat(density)),
                 data = subset(model.frame(dstrat), stype == "E"),
                 breaks = 0:35 * 100,
                 position = "identity", col = "gray50") +
  geom_histogram(aes(fill = "Not E", weight = pw, y = after_stat(density)),
                 data = subset(model.frame(dstrat), stype != "E"),
                 position = "identity", col = "gray50",
                 breaks = 0:7 * 500) +
  scale_fill_manual(NULL, values = c("#00880020", "#88000020")) +
  theme_classic()
```

[image]

Comment: The problem with this is that it doesn't use the sampling weights

Comment: @ThomasLumley good point. I have updated to show how to use the sampling weights within the ggplot framework, including a ggplot version of your nicely demonstrated example. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You can't just extract the data and use `ggplot`, because that won't use the weights and so misses the whole point of `svyhist`.  You can use the `add=TRUE` argument, though.  You **do** need to set the x and y axis ranges correctly to make sure the whole plot is visible

Using the data example from `?svyhist`

```
svyhist(~enroll, subset(dstrat,stype=="E"), col="#00880020",ylim=c(0,0.003),xlim=c(0,3500))
svyhist(~enroll, subset(dstrat,stype!="E"), col="#88000020",add=TRUE)
```

[image]